# Error in ExecuteNonQuery command in C#, can't update database

Tags: c#-4.0

here is the code that i have written for change password in my website in C#, but it shows the error in "ExecuteNonQuery()" command..and i cant update the database with new password... i have tried many solution for that like i have check permission in windows authentication for modify the "Database" file..
-> Code in Change.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\PlacementCell\PlacementCell\Database.mdb";
    conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string str1 = "select * from Student_Login where Password ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str1, conn);
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\PlacementCell\PlacementCell\Database.mdb");
        con1.Open();
        string str = "UPDATE Student_Login SET Password=" + TextBox3.Text + "where Password= " + TextBox1.Text;
        using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(str, con1))
        {
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Label1.Visible = true;
        con1.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Label3.Visible = true;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

...................
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qoHa.jpg)

Comment: you are missing a double quote at the end of your update statement. Could you please check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are a few syntax issues within your existing code, such as missing quotes around your parameter values when building your queries and concatenating your strings like the following line :

```
string str = "UPDATE Student_Login SET Password='" + TextBox3.Text + "' where Password= " + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

A bigger issue here is that you aren't using SQL Parameterization, which can cause issues like this to occur (and lead to SQL Injection vulnerabilities). Consider the following code, which should resolve all of your previous issues and keep you protected against any injection-based nastiness:

```
// Create your connection
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\PlacementCell\PlacementCell\Database.mdb"))
{
    // Build your first query
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Student_Login WHERE Password = @password";
    // Create a command to execute your query
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
            // Open your connection
            conn.Open();
            // Add your parameter (prevents SQL Injection and syntax issues)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);

            // Execute your query into a reader
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                    // Go through each row
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        // Build an update query
                        var updateQuery = "UPDATE Student_LogIn SET Password = @password WHERE Password = @oldPassword";
                        // Build a new command to execute
                        using (var updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, conn))
                        {
                            // Set a parameter and execute
                            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text);
                            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldPassword", TextBox1.Text);
                            // Execute your query
                            updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Label1.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

You can also try this version which doesn't rely on named parameters :

```
// Create your connection
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\PlacementCell\PlacementCell\Database.mdb"))
{
    // Build your first query
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Student_Login WHERE Password = ?";
    // Create a command to execute your query
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
            // Open your connection
            conn.Open();
            // Add your parameter (prevents SQL Injection and syntax issues)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);

            // Execute your query into a reader
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                    // Go through each row
                    while(dr.Read())
                    {
                        // Build an update query
                        var updateQuery = "UPDATE Student_LogIn SET Password = ? WHERE Password = ?";
                        // Build a new command to execute
                        using (var updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, conn))
                        {
                            // Set a parameter and execute
                            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text);
                            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldPassword", TextBox1.Text);
                            // Execute your query
                            updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Label1.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this..but again there is same error..!!

Comment: Did you use the second approach that I mentioned? String concatenation as you are currently using is never really safe and leads to issues like the one you are fighting with.

Comment: Can you post a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of what your updated code looks like? I don't see any areas that would have syntax errors as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try using the updated approach I provided in my update. Basically replace the parameters that begin within `@` in your query with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once this...

updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
updateCmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = TextBox3.Text;

updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@oldPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar);
updateCmd.Parameters["@oldPassword"].Value = TextBox1.Text;